# IE10 text-overflow ellipsis not working

Tags: internet-explorer-10, css

I have an `<a>` tag in html, and I want it to be ellipsis. But when I add a `<div>` inside the `<a>` tag, 'text-overflow' doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class=boxed>
  <h1>text-overflow Attribute Sample</h1>
    <a href="#" class="caption">
      <!----><div style="width:100px;height:20px;border: 1px solid red"></div>
      Each box (div element) below contains the following text:
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.boxed {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font: 14px Times New Roman, serif;
    overflow:hidden;
    'position:relative;
}
a.caption {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPzsy/

After removing the `<div>`, the 'text-overflow' works again.

Comment: In your CSS, there is a `'` right before `position:`. Also in your jsFiddle. Maybe this is an error?

Comment: A is an inline element. Div is a block element. You are not supposed to put block elements inside inline elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **div** is a block level element and **a** is an inline level element, so you cannot use a **div** inside an anchor tag **b**...so you should use any other inline tag (like **small** , **span** etc)

Secondly, if you have to use a **div** inside **div**, you can wrap your text in another tag like this ....

```
<div class=boxed>
     <h1>text-overflow Attribute Sample</h1>
     <div class="caption">
         <!----><div style=" width:100px;height:20px;border: 1px solid red"></div>
         <span class='textTrunc'>Each box (div element) below contains the following text:</span>
  </div>
```

and css of class **textTrunc**:

```
.textTrunc{  
    overflow:hidden;  
    white-space: nowrap;  
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
    display:block;  
}
```

Comment: Actually, in HTML5, you are allowed to wrap elements with an `a` element.