# Not able to set text ellipsis for input placeholder in IE11

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer-11, placeholder, ellipsis

I'm able to set the color of input placeholder text in IE11 (Windows 7) but I'm not able to set text overflow to ellipsis for input placeholder text.

Here is the jsfiddle to reproduce this issue (Please open this fiddle link in IE11 on windows 7) ,

`https://jsfiddle.net/1nku0aty/3/`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext">
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  margin: 2em;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
}
```

Can some one help on solving this?

Comment: What sense would such a long placeholder text, that gets cut off with an ellipsis, make to begin with? I will never be able to read it in its entirety, so what purpose does it serve in the first place? [Placeholders are already considered harmful](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/) - and you need to add an additional layer of bad UX on top of this …?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better answer to this question about IE10:

[Placeholder text-overflow:ellipsis in IE10 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485598/placeholder-text-overflowellipsis-in-ie10-not-working)

Basically, apparently it doesn't work unless you make the input field readonly, it is possible to do some hacky javascript to make it readonly except when you click it, but if you have the option of going 'eh whatever, it's IE11 and a minor glitch, who cares' you should probably take that...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. That doesn't work in IE as usual.

```css
input[placeholder]{
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
input{
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="loremipsumdolorsitametconsetetur">
```