# Text-overflow: ellipsis is spacing weirdly on IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ellipsis

I'm using text-overflow: ellipsis in IE10, and it's displaying the ellipses strangely, spaced very widely. I thought it might be a font issue so I changed the font to Arial, but it's still happening.

[image]

If I type an ellipsis, it's displayed normally. Not really sure what's causing this.

[image]

Comment: Is this three dots “...”, dots with spaces “. . .” or the Unicode character “…”? Which one looks the closest to IE’s ellipsis?

Comment: @Xufox The one that I've typed, that displays normal, is the unicode character '…'. The one that is displaying weirdly is from the css property "text-overflow: ellipsis;", which I assume would also use the unicode character.

Comment: But the same Unicode character shouldn’t look different.

Comment: The one displaying oddly is generated from the CSS property, I don't know what exactly it's doing there.. The one displaying correctly is a typed character.

Comment: Okay then the CSS one is probably “. . .” which is an acceptable alternative to “…” as far as I remember…or one that was to be avoided…

Comment: If IE supported it you could use `text-overflow:'…';` but unfortunately, it doesn’t. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) the form of “. . .” is actually one of the most common forms but IE [isn’t following the standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#ellipsis). So, are you asking for a workaround to fix this in IE?

Comment: “_Implementations may substitute a more language, script, or writing-mode appropriate ellipsis character_” Okay, IE actually does follow the standard, apparently.

Comment: It's only happening in IE10, IE11 renders it normally and we're not supporting IE9 (praise the lord). All other browsers render normally. It's not a dealbreaker but I was hoping there was a simple answer.

Comment: Here is some kind of accepted answer and maybe it is appropriate to this problem also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691919/ie10-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working